# Want to run PsExec parallelly in multiple machines

Tags: java, windows, automation, multiprocessing, psexec

I have a set of remote machines which are maintained in a file. I am iterating the machine list in my java code and I want to run some bat files in those machines parallelly (at a time).

Can someone help me How can I run PsExec to invoke multiple machines at a time?

Your help really appreciate! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Save a file named pc_info.txt same location as your batch is saved. Put the list of PC in file pc_info.txt.

```
 @echo off
    for /F  %%M  in  (pc_info.txt) do (

    ping -n 1 -w 1 %%M >nul
    if errorlevel 1 echo %%M is down >> c:\temp\pc_down_info.txt

    If not errorlevel 1 (
    cd c:\psexec
    psexec -d \\%%M "C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise\mcupdate.exe" /update
    )
    )
    pause
```

This code will run the DVDMaker.exe in every pc listed in pc_infor.txt. And will input the PC names that is down/offline in c:\temp\pc_down_info.txt.